# How to Create Empty folders under Microsoft Teams --> Channel using Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using Graph API for creation of Teams and then channels. But after the creation of a channel I want to add some empty folders inside that. How can Achieve this using graph API ?
[Team -> Channel -> File -> Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc1ED.png)

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the metadata for the location where the folders or files of a channel are stored.

```
GET /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/filesFolder
```

The response returns `driveItem` resource with `driveId` and `driveItem's` `id`.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#teams('32e3b156-66b2-4135-9aeb-73295a35a55b')/channels('19%3Af253e46c035b42308e9a4a22a87037af%40thread.skype')/filesFolder/$entity",
    "id": "01H7CFEKENJSSIUHGADZBKODARINQC5JMD",
    "createdDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-01-23T18:47:13Z",
    "name": "Documentation Planning",
    "webUrl": "xxx",
    "size": 2374080,
    "parentReference": {
        "driveId": "b!2SInBlQrN0K8-GXMy9qNsPtI5ScW8C5IlZtycoy6ZpJZRRtgE4qVTrE8wrvL0-hd",
        "driveType": "documentLibrary"
    },
    ...
}
```

Then you can create a new folder by calling the endpoint:

```
POST /drives/{driveId}/items/{id}/children
```

[Get files folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get-filesfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[Create folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-post-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Thanks It helped.

Comment: You are a life saver.  Searched and tried for a whole day through the API and just couldn't get it.  Thought I needed to use the /groups version.  And even the /drives/{drive-id}/items/{parent-item-id}/children version is confusing with parent-item-id that is really the drive-item-id. Bravo!